# How to ensure Django updates html to reflect changes?

Tags: python, django

Expected Result:

I expect to see `<p>B<p/>` when I edit my home page from `<p>A<p/>`  to `<p>B<p/>`, save changes in the editor, and refresh the browser.

Actual Results:

I'm seeing `<p>A<p/>` when I edit my home page from `<p>A<p/>`  to `<p>B<p/>`, save changes in the editor, and refresh the browser.

A week ago I was getting the "Expected results" but I noticed a few days ago I'm getting the results explained in "Actual Results". Now Only when I restart the server by running docker-compose up restart I'm getting the expected results.

Why simple HTML changes not being updated when I refresh the browser? I'm using Django 3.1 and Python 3.7.

Edit:

Docker file:

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.7-slim

# Set environment varibles
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /projects

# Install dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /projects/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

# Copy project
COPY . /projects/
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /projects/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    # command: gunicorn guyanaNPPM_project.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000
    environment:
    
      - "DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=hidden for security reasons"
      - "DJANGO_DEBUG=True"
      - "DJANGO_SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER=True"
      - "DJANGO_SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=False"
      - "DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS=0"
      - "DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS=False"
      - "DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD=False"
      - "DJANGO_SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=False"
      - "DJANGO_CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE=False"
    
    volumes:
      - .:/projects
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:11
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment: 
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Comment: There are a million reasons this could happen. Caching is a likely candidate, whether in your browser (did you "empty cache and hard reload"?) or somewhere along the line between your server and browser. Are you using a live reloading development server, e.g. `python manage.py runserver`? If not, you may need to restart your server (e.g. Gunicorn).

Comment: I empty cache and hard reload. I'm using `python manage.py runserver` for development and Gunicorn for production. I'm getting the same problem with this website when I host it on heroku. Only when I logout and Login can I see the updates to values in the database for the version on heroku.

Comment: "I'm getting the same problem with this website when I host it on heroku"—no, you're getting _correct_ behaviour if you host on Heroku. You shouldn't be editing templates live on your server at all. And if you do, you should _expect_ to have to restart your server for the changes to appear. But on Heroku this is a nonstarter due to its ephemeral filesystem. If you want to change your template on Heroku you'll need to change it locally, commit the change, and redeploy. But that's a different issue.

Comment: Please show us how you are running your server in development. You'll probably have to show your `Dockerfile` and, if you have one, your `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml added to the original question. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Try `docker-compose stop ; docker-compose rm -f ; docker-compose pull` before you use `docker-compose` to launch your django project.

If this suggestion works, then you may forget to update your docker image when relaunching your django project, or your local source does not sync up with the code base in the running docker container instance.